# How to add/use lightGallery plugin with Angular 4+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying to use [lightGallery](https://github.com/youpinyao/angular-lightgallery) in my Angular 4 project, I am able to make it work by adding these to the index.html file

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery.js@1.0.2/dist/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
<script>
    lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
</script>
```

**Problem**
How do I use the lightGallery within angular code (typescript), as I can invoke lightGallery() upon loading the (dynamic content)pictures?

I have tried many options like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)

or How can I use custom JavaScript code in an angular component?

Comment: have you seen this [post](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af) ?

Comment: thanks! yes, I have followed similar articles. I was able to use jQuery and other libraries that way, but I couldn't make lightGallery library work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the library after the steps described below

1. Add lightgallery.js library file to a local folder (assets)
2. Add the file path to the scripts array of the .angular-cli.json

   `"scripts": [
       "../src/assets/js/lightgallery.min.js"
   ]`
3. Import lightgallery.css file in the style.css file

   `@import "~lightgallery.js/dist/css/lightgallery.css"; // add this on top of style.css`
4. Add this line of code on top of the component class file, where it is needed

   `declare var lightGallery: any; // this will prevent typescript compiler complaining about "lightGallery" not found`
5. Invoke lightGallery anywhere within the component as below

   `lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));`